# Simple Php String Matching Pattern

Tags: php, string, match

I have two strings I need to compare.  Let's say for example that the strings are as follows:

```
$A = "A fox jumped over the log";
$B = "A fox jumped";
```

Now how would I compare these two strings in PHP in order to return a percentage of character matching.

So I would like my algorithm to return (for the example above)

10/20 or .5 Since $B has exactly half of the matches of the length of $A.

I figured I could iterate through each character, but this seemed a bit tedious and my research indicated that preg_match wouldn't help me much here.  Thanks for the help!

Comment: if a character appears twice in the first string but only once in the second string is that 1/2 or 2/2?

Comment: also, does position matter? if you have `a fox jumped` and `_a fox jumped` is that a 0% match because the second string is offset by 1?

Comment: I updated my question to be more clear.  In my case, string B will always be the first part of string A.  So I need to detect if a string (lets say string X) is contained within string A.  If so, it will look like string B

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try the [levenshtein](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.levenshtein.php) or [similar_text](http://php.net/manual/en/function.similar-text.php) functions.